# How to use Ajax response data in another form?

Tags: ajax, laravel, forms

I have a page with 2 forms:

1. regular form
2. hidden modal that pops up when the first form is submitted successfully.

I use ajax to send the first form, and successfully retrieve the data.

Now I want my modal to have a form, that has default values based on the response.

This is my current Ajax script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});

$(".btn-submit").click(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = $('#area_selector').serialize();

    $.ajax({
       type:'POST',
       url:"{{ url('ajaxRequest') }}",
       data: formData,
       success:function(data, response){
          //$('#ajax-response').append('<div class="help-block">' + data + '</div>'); // add the actual error message under our input
          var address = data.address.address;
          var form = $(
        '<form name = "test"' +
        '<label for="exampleInputEmail1">Address</label>' +
        '<input type="text" id="title" value = ' +
        address +
        'name="address" class="form-control"> </form>'
        );
        $('#ajax-response').append(form);
          //var address_being_edited = data.address.address;

          //$('#ajax-response').append('Address: ' + data.address.address + '<br>');
          //$('#ajax-response').append('Current Area: ' + data.current_area.name);

          $("#exampleModal").modal('show');

          //console.log(data);
          console.log(data.address.address);
          
       }
    });

});
```

I want my form to have 2 inputs, whose default values are those in `data.address.address` and 'data.current_area.name'.

My (empty) modal right now:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Edit your address:</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div id = "ajax-response">

        </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-submit2">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How do I do this?

Comment: It looks like everything is set, are you being able to get the response for this console.log that you've write in the code? Or some error is happening?

Comment: No it's not an error, I just don't know how to populate the forms with the response data. I've tried using append but aside from the fact that it is an extremely annoying and a way I consider "stupid" it threw a syntax error.

This is how I tried adding the first field of the form:

```$('#ajax-response').append('<label for="exampleInputEmail1">Address</label>          
<input type="text" id="title" value = ' + data.address.address + ' name="address" class="form-control">');```

^ above code throws a syntax error

Comment: Hmm Okay, lemme send a piece of code here and you try follow it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try doing something like this:

```
$('#ajax-response').innerHTML = `
  <form id="myForm">
    <input type="text" id="address" value="${data.address.address}" /> <br>
    <input type="text" id="currentArea" value="${data.current_area.name}" /> <br>
  </form>
`
```

Comment: I will try this but I already figured a semi-working solution, I will update the script.

I say semi-working because it is truncating the address. 

So, instead of the address being "19 Hosny El Ashmawy" it drops everything after the space, returning only 19. Logging the object to console returns the correct address, so I'm not sure why it's being truncated.

Comment: Could you please look at the update? Like I said, it displays the address but truncates everything after the space.

Comment: Okay, try using template string like this: (` <code> `), makes the code more readable. And the code has some errors, can update them? First one is the form tag is not being closed with ">" ( '<form name = "test">' instead of ' <form name = "test" ' ). Second one is  that you need to wrap the address with quotes ( value=" ' + address + ' " instead of  value = ' + address + '  )

Comment: And just a tip, it's always preferable to use const and let instead of var. var's aren't scoped based, this can led to errors

Comment: Thank you, it was because I forgot the double quotes around value. Thank you very much :)